# Why am I getting slower transfer speeds than expected with Cat7 cables?

Tags: networking, router

A friend had some extra [AmazonBasics RJ45 Cat7 Ethernet patch cables](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013PUMQYY) and gave them to me. I’m using a Netgear AC1200 Smart Wi-Fi router with my laptop and desktop. Both devices using the new Cat7 cables and new-ish SSDs.

With both SSH and HTTP I'm getting only 11.5 MB/s down between the two devices. I've tried transferring several large 4K MKVs (50 GB files) between the two devices and can't seen to max more than 11.5 MB/s. These speeds are no better than my previous Cat5E cables.

Am I missing something? Is there a limitation of my router or should I be getting faster transfer speeds? What can I do to debug/investigate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the fine print on the Amazon page it says your router has

> Five (5) 10/100 (1 WAN & 4 LAN) Fast Ethernet ports

So it won't matter what cables you use - you're not going to get more than 100 Mbit/sec. Which is about 10 MB/s. Which seems to be what you're getting.

In short, yes, it's a limitation of your router.

Before you buy a new router... it may *also* be a limitation of the Ethernet ports on your machines. Check both of them to be sure they have gigabit Ethernet ports. If they don't, then a router with gigabit ports won't help.

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that at the bottom of the product description. Thank you for this answer. Time to buy a new router!